# Swift: Group nested array by multiple criteria - improving algorithm

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, grouping

I have an array of Objects with multiple properties. I need to group it by those properties into sections. I've already wrote al algorithm which does that. However, I'd like to have a more succinct and reusable one, so that I can group items in a different manner.

Given an array of objects:

```
@objcMembers class Object: NSObject {
    let name: UUID = UUID()
    let value1: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
    let value2: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
    let value3: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
    static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

```
[
    Object1 {4, 4, 1},
    Object2 {1, 3, 2},
    ...
    Object99 {3, 4, 2},
]
```

... and given two data structure, `Group` and `Section`:

```
struct Group {
    let title: String?
    let sections: [Section]
}

struct Section {
    let title: String?
    let items: [Object]
}
```

I need to get the following result:

```
Value1: 1 // Group
    Value2: 1 - Value3: 1 // Section
        Object1
        Object2
        Object3
    Value2: 1 - Value3: 2 // Section
        Object1
    Value2: 2 - Value3: 1 // Section
        Object1
        Object2
        Object3
Value1: 2 // Group
    Value2: 1 - Value3: 5 // Section
        Object1
    Value2: 4 - Value3: 1 // Section
        Object1
    Value2: 4 - Value3: 2 // Section
        Object1
        Object2
        Object3
```

So, that the objects are grouped into `sections` by their `Value3` and `Value2` and sorted in ascending order.

Then, these sections are grouped into `groups` by their `Value1` and, again, sorted in ascending order.

My current algorithm implemented in a basic imperative approach and I'm sure has a lot of points to be improved.

I've already tried to use Swift's [Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) initialiser and then [Dictionary.mapValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995348-mapvalues) method to group entries further. However, Swift's dictionaries are not ordered, so I have to do a deep sort again.

Currently, my algorithm looks like this:

```
        // Sort the array
        let value1BasedDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.value1, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.value2, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.value3, ascending: true),
        ]
        let sorted = (Array(objects) as NSArray).sortedArray(using: value1BasedDescriptors) as! [Object]

        // Keep the previous object to find when one of the properties change
        var previousObject: Object?
        // Keep the group to be filled with sections
        var currentGroup = [Section]()
        // Keep the section to be filled with objects
        var currentSection = [Object]()
        // All the groups to be returned by the function
        var groups = [Group]()

        // Iterate over each object
        for object in sorted {
            // If it's a first time in a loop, set a previous object and skip
            if previousObject == nil {
                previousObject = object
                // Append to the current section
                currentSection.append(object)
                continue
            }
            // If one of the value3 or value2 is different from the previously visited object -> Create a new section with the appropriate title
            if object.value3 != previousObject?.value3 || object.value2 != previousObject?.value2 {
                let section = Section(title: "Value2: \(previousObject?.value2) - Value3: \(previousObject?.value3)", items: currentSection)
                // Add it to current group
                currentGroup.append(section)
                // Empty the section
                currentSection.removeAll()
            }

            // If Value1 is different, group all the objects into group
            if object.value1 != previousObject?.value1 {
                let group = Group(title: "Value1: \(previousObject?.value1)", sections: currentGroup)
                groups.append(group)
                currentGroup.removeAll()
            }

            // Always add a visited object to a current section
            currentSection.append(object)

            // And mark as previous
            previousObject = object
        }

        // since the last group & section won't be added in a loop, we have to add them manually
        let section = Section(title: "Value2: \(previousObject?.value2) - Value3: \(previousObject?.value3)", items: currentSection)
        currentGroup.append(section)
        let group = Group(title: "Value1: \(previousObject?.value1)", sections: currentGroup)
        groups.append(group)


        debugPrint(groups)
```

It does exactly what I need to achieve, however, here are the limitations:

1. What if I want to group the objects in the following order: Value2 -> Value1 -> Value3 ? Or any other order? Then I'll have to write the same algorithm, but changing the properties
2. If I have to write the same algorithm multiple times, how can I make it shorter, e.g. utilising Functional or OOP methods?

Full code listing (copy-paste to Playground or the `AppDelegate.swift` file):

```
        struct Group {
            let title: String?
            let sections: [Section]
        }

        struct Section {
            let title: String?
            let items: [Object]
        }

        @objcMembers class Object: NSObject {
            let name: UUID = UUID()
            let value1: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
            let value2: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
            let value3: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
            static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
                lhs.name == rhs.name
            }
        }

        // Create a lot of objects
        var objects = Set<Object>()
        for i in 0...100 {
            objects.insert(Object())
        }

        // Sort the array
        let value1BasedDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.value1, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.value2, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.value3, ascending: true),
        ]
        let sorted = (Array(objects) as NSArray).sortedArray(using: value1BasedDescriptors) as! [Object]

        // Keep the previous object to find when one of the properties change
        var previousObject: Object?
        // Keep the group to be filled with sections
        var currentGroup = [Section]()
        // Keep the section to be filled with objects
        var currentSection = [Object]()
        // All the groups to be returned by the function
        var groups = [Group]()

        // Iterate over each object
        for object in sorted {
            // If it's a first time in a loop, set a previous object and skip
            if previousObject == nil {
                previousObject = object
                // Append to the current section
                currentSection.append(object)
                continue
            }
            // If one of the value3 or value2 is different from the previously visited object -> Create a new section with the appropriate title
            if object.value3 != previousObject?.value3 || object.value2 != previousObject?.value2 {
                let section = Section(title: "Value2: \(previousObject?.value2) - Value3: \(previousObject?.value3)", items: currentSection)
                // Add it to current group
                currentGroup.append(section)
                // Empty the section
                currentSection.removeAll()
            }

            // If Value1 is different, group all the objects into group
            if object.value1 != previousObject?.value1 {
                let group = Group(title: "Value1: \(previousObject?.value1)", sections: currentGroup)
                groups.append(group)
                currentGroup.removeAll()
            }

            // Always add a visited object to a current section
            currentSection.append(object)

            // And mark as previous
            previousObject = object
        }

        // since the last group & section won't be added in a loop, we have to add them manually
        let section = Section(title: "Value2: \(previousObject?.value2) - Value3: \(previousObject?.value3)", items: currentSection)
        currentGroup.append(section)
        let group = Group(title: "Value1: \(previousObject?.value1)", sections: currentGroup)
        groups.append(group)


        debugPrint(groups)
```

Comment: `arc4random_uniform` is obsolete in Swift, btw. Use `Int.random(in: 1...6)`.

Comment: Thank you. It's just a reference code to provide a minimum reproducible sample to see the algorithm in action.

Comment: What pops into my head is ... "use one data-structure to store the records, maybe as a simple list, and then construct the nested structures - maybe even 'on the fly' - as *indexes* to them, which point to the objects that are stored in the list.

Comment: Could you spend some time simplifying this code? E.g. all of the sort descriptors and sets need to go. They could just be written as `(0...10)
 .map { _ in Object() }
 .sorted(by: { ($0.value1, $0.value2, $0.value3) < ($1.value1, $1.value2, $1.value3)})`. Is `@objcMembers` necessary for your problem, or were you forced into that because you were tried to use `NSArray`?

Comment: @Alexander Good suggestion. Yes, I had to use `@objcMembers` in order to use `NSSortDescriptor`. However, that doesn't change the core of the problem.

Please, consider the sorting a part of the grouping algorithm. The main problem to be tackled is grouping and keeping the order right.

Considering the array already sorted, how can I group it into the proposed structure?

How to extract this algorithm to make it reusable or simple enough to keep duplicate.

Comment: @MikeRobinson transforming the structure on the fly is out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this. I would use `Dictionary(_:groupingBy:)` to produce a groups, and then take that dictionary as the input to a mapping process, transforming the key:value pairs into `Group` objects. The mapping itself involves another process, calling `Dictionary(_:groupingBy:)` to group by `value2`, mapping those key:value pairs into `Section` objects.

To add the customization you're looking for, you can replace this nesting of these repeating `Dictionary(_:groupingBy:)`, `map` and `sorted` calls can be replaces with recursion, by taking an array of keypaths (which represent the values by which you want the various layers grouped by)

```
import Foundation

struct Object: Equatable {
//  let name: UUID = UUID()
    let value1 = Int.random(in: 1...6)
    let value2 = Int.random(in: 1...6)
    let value3 = Int.random(in: 1...6)

    static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.value1, lhs.value2, lhs.value3) == (rhs.value1, rhs.value2, rhs.value3)
    }
}

extension Object: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.value1, lhs.value2, lhs.value3) < (rhs.value1, rhs.value2, rhs.value3)
    }
}

struct Group: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    let title: String
    let sections: [Section]

    var debugDescription: String {
        let sectionText = self.sections
            .map { "\t" + $0.debugDescription }
            .joined(separator: "\n")

        return "Group: \(self.title)\n\(sectionText)"
    }
}

struct Section: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    let title: String
    let items: [Object]

    var debugDescription: String {
        let itemText = self.items
            .map { "\t\t" + String(describing: $0) }
            .joined(separator: "\n")

        return "Section: \(self.title)\n\(itemText)"
    }
}

let input = (0...100).map { _ in Object() }.sorted()

let groups = Dictionary(grouping: input, by: { $0.value1 })
    .map { (arg: (key: Int, rawSections: [Object])) -> Group in
        let (key, rawSections) = arg
        let sections = Dictionary(grouping: rawSections, by: { $0.value2 })
            .map { key, objects in
                Section(title: String(key), items: objects.sorted { $0.value3 < $1.value3 })
            }
            .sorted { $0.title < $1.title }
        return Group(title: String(key), sections: sections)
    }
    .sorted(by: { $0.title < $1.title })

for group in groups {
    debugPrint(group)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks interesting. As I understand, you've decided to follow the path of simplifying an algorithm instead of making it more reusable.

I have a couple of questions: 1. Do we really need an initial sort (just after creating the object array) ? 2. The objects are `Comparable` in your implementation. What if the grouping logic change? I.e. group not by the `Value1` at first, but by the `Value3`?

Comment: 1. Nope, the sort isn't necessary there, I just did it to show off its simplicity compared to compare against `NSSortDescriptor` 2. you could use `sorted(by:)` (instead of `sorted()`), whose closure defines an ad-hoc sort order. 3. If you want the grouping logic to change, you could follow the rouge idea I layed out, of using an array of KeyPaths, to pick which values are used for the 3 levels. Right now it's limited to 3 levels, given the hard-coded nature of `Group` and `Section`. Those two types are very similar, so I would recommend merging them, and just using the 1 type for all layers.

Comment: In what way could I merge those two types into one? Could you provide an example? I could think of using generics for defining the `items` property type

Comment: I'm working on it, here's my first start: https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Generalized-Grouping-WIP I'll finish it up later as I have time. But the idea is to recursively build groups, one layer at a time, by consuming the keypaths in the passed-in array, one by one.

Comment: Thank you. I had a different idea in mind - to create an extension `split(where: {previousElement, nextElement})`, so that the array could be split iteration by iteration into chunks (considered the array has been already sorted).

It'v very similar to the Dictionary.groupingBy initializer, but since it's an Array, it will  keep the order intact.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy That works too, but if you want this nice nesting behaviour (which is how I understood your problem), you still need a recursive algorithm that takes your elements (split apart nicely or not), and wires them together in a nicely nested heirarchy.

Comment: Yes, and the recursive (or a for-loop example) algorithm still will work: 1. sort with NSSortDescriptors (there are 5+ criteria!), 2. Group by `level1`, 3. For individual "leaf" array apply the same method to group by `level2`, 4. Group this time by `level3` 5. Iterate through the resulting structure by creating Groups & sections with the appropriate headers.
it's inefficient (a couple of array passes instead of only 1-2 in the other examples) but it's rather simply to modify and clean.
The number of `Item`s won't exceed 1000, so the algorithm is perfectly valid to be run on the main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202355/discussion-between-alexander-and-richard-topchiy).